# Having trouble echoing a picture with php

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
    $filedir = 'uploads/';
    echo "<img src='$filedir".$user->data()->username."'></img>";   
?>
```

Can someone please help and maybe explain how to echo with PHP.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read **[How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. We're missing some information - could you share the class associated with `$user`? What is the output of `$user->data()->username`?

Comment: image tag must close <img .... />

Comment: **echo $filedir.$user->data()->username;** and check image available in this location

Comment: Yes i am terribly sorry i forgot to tell that $user->data->usename is getting the users username from a database i have set up. Please tell if you need any more information.

Comment: Rahautos, i the output was the image name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note **your path look like**.
>
> If `$user` value is `'abdulla'`, then path is `uploads/abdulla`. In here no file extension is mentioned(`.jpg` /`.png`)

**After Debug your code**

```
<?php
    $filedir = 'uploads/';
    $user = $user->data()->username;
    if (isset($user))  {
        ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $filedir ?>/<?php echo $user ?>"/>
        <?php
    } else {
        echo 'User is empty';
    }

?>
```

***Improved code***

```
<?php
    $filedir = 'uploads/';
    $user = $user->data()->username;
    if (isset($user))  {
        ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $filedir ?>/<?php echo $user ?>.jpg"/>
        <?php
    } else {
        echo 'User is empty';
    }

?>
```

this show path as `uploads/abdulla.jpg`

Comment: Thank you it worked! I thought you could echo it without the extension. Once again thank you

Comment: Use minimal code for pretty HTML and understand batter

Comment: @GaurangJoshi you are correct. but if OP is Beginner to PHP we have to use full code to better understand. Thanks any way

Comment: @downvoter please specify why?? **OP accepted that's works**

Comment: No Problem @Abdulla you are welcome. i'll follow your teaching path. :)

Comment: @GaurangJoshi Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below:

```
<?php
$filedir = 'uploads/';
?>
<img src="<?php echo $filedir.$user->data()->username?>"/>;
```

Comment: This won't make a difference - he's `echo`ing the string in double quotations, so the `$filedir` string will output "uploads/".

Comment: have you saved your image with extension.. like  JPEG,PNG or anything else..?

Comment: Is username and image name both are same..?